# Creating Reboot Procedure For Legacy Linux Server

Tags: linux, unix

I have a legacy Linux System which has some processes ( manually or automatically started )  running under different users. The server is not restarted since long time, and current staff doesn't know what specifically must be run there and what to start manually after restart.

I have to do a storage migration so that, I'll shutdown and restart it.

In Windows, I can open services.msc and note "manually started" and "automatically but stopped" processes for proper restart even if I don't know what is running there.

What is the procedure for Linux to learn exactly what to restart or what to stop and how to do it after proper reboot ?

Comment: which linux variant ?

Comment: For example rhel 5

Comment: What is the uptime of the system?

Comment: Uptime is 712 days

Answer (score 1):

Under a RHEL or CentOS-based system, pay attention to what services are set to run by checking the `chkconfig list` or `ntsysv` commands.

For any individual processes that run under particular users, take note of them. See if you can identify the programs in a `ps -ef` output, for example.

Comment: Can you set up a copy to experiment? You should consider installing and upgrading a new machine, and migrating this stuff there (2 years without kernel and other updates... **shudder**).